# Listing Multiple elements inside single row item of custom list view using adapter?

Tags: android, android-listview

--- > I have created a Listview with custom adapter.

---- > I have designed the row item , with a textview and listview (list view to display multiple sub items)

---- > problem comes when adding items to secondary sub list.

----- > Kindly guide me how to add items in the sub list inside the row item.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Need a list view inside the each row of a parent list view

Answer (score 0):

To add items in the `sublist` which is also a `list` present inside each row, all you need is to `bind a adapter` with items to the `sublist` in the `parent` list overloaded `getView` method.